# Storyboard and expandable textView

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitextview, autolayout

I've try to setup expandable `textView` in storyboard using `autolayout`.

Here is how i setup the constrains:

[image]
[image]

The field near "Description" is `UITextView`. I want it to expand it depend on how much line text field contains.

The tree structure of the view is:
`UIView` -> `UITextView`

And I now do it by:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

And it expand the `UITextView` as expected to the bottom of parent View. But my task is:

1. Expand the textfield as expected.
2. Expand the `height` of the parent view also to save the margin of the bottom.

As you can see i'm mess around with `frame` but i'm got this feeling that I need to do it using constrains. Can you suggest a proper solution?

Comment: Connect `IBOutlet` to constraints and update it's value instead of changing frame. Adding height constraint to parent and updating it may done the task.

Comment: yeah, you're right - this do the trick. Should be an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

- Add height constraint to `parentView` of `UITextView`
- Connect `IBOutlet` to that height constraint
- Update that constraint programatically in `textViewDidChange:` method

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do without updating constraint programatically. The key is unchecking the "Scrolling enabled" field on textview and setting view's height constraint to be greater or equal than the initial constant.